# A more Pythonic one-liner solution?

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a more Pythonic one-liner to split and flatten lists. The original list looks like this:

```
negative_list = [['apple strudel', 'apple, orange, pear ice cream']]
```

With the above un-processed list, I need to transform it to the following processed list:

```
negative_list = ['apple strudel', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear ice cream']
```

You will notice that 'apple', 'orange', 'pear ice cream' have been split into individual items in the transformed list.

I wrote the following:

```
negative_list = []
negatives = []
negative_list = [['apple strudel', 'apple, orange, pear ice cream']]
negative_list = [item for sublist in negative_list for item in sublist]
for i in negative_list: 
    if ',' not in i: negatives.append(i.strip())
    else:
        for element in i.split(','): negatives.append(element.strip())
print(negative_list)
print(negatives)
```

I tried writing a Pythonic one-liner without declaring so many variables, but with little success. Could someone help?

Comment: "one-liner" != Pythonic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this solution, although this is not recommended for production code:

```
negative_list = [['apple strudel', 'apple, orange, pear ice cream']]

negative_list = sum([elem.split(", ") for elem in negative_list[0]],[])
print(negative_list)
```

Output:

```
['apple strudel', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear ice cream']
```

Another way is to use a nested `for` loop with `list-comprehension`:

```
negative_list = [elem.strip() for item in negative_list[0] for elem in item.split(", ")]
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but what do you mean by 'production code'?

Comment: In case you want to ship your program for others to use it. To commercially publish it.

Comment: Do you say that because it is too difficult to understand? It is clever but I certainly find it difficult to understand!

Comment: This may be asking too much - but could you explain the 'negative_list[0]' bit? How do you manage to access all elements of the list by calling the very first element alone?

Comment: sum to flatten lists is an anti-pattern

Comment: @CodeMonkey, Your list contains only one element which is also a list. `[.., ..]` contains two elements. `[[], []]` contains two elements - both lists. `[[..]]` contains one element which is a list (your case). :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey, you have a list (`negative_list`) which contains one element, which is a list. So in order to access that element (which is the first and the only element of the list), you have to point at it using `0` as index.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with a generator expression:

```
from itertools import chain

negative_list = [['apple strudel', 'apple, orange, pear ice cream']]

print(list(chain.from_iterable(x.split(', ') for x in negative_list[0])))
# ['apple strudel', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear ice cream']
```

Comment: This. No reason to check if comma is in the string, as split will return a list of length zero when it doesn’t.

Answer (score -1):

I think this one resolves the problem

```
x = [['apple strudel', 'apple, orange, pear ice cream'], ["test", "test1, test2, test3"]]

def flatten(x):
    return sum([(x.split(", ")) for x in sum(x, [])], [])

print(flatten(x))
```

Comment: sum to flatten lists is an anti-pattern

Comment: But I think this is the only way to flatten this in one line as asked in the question